# Change Excel Column Background colour with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

For a Excel document that is becoming larger then the internet I am trying to get rid of automatic lay outs cause they are seriously slowing our excel to an extend where its becomes non usable.

I attempted to create a macro that colours the background of a cell based on the active cell value.

```
  Sub find()

 Dim CurValue  As String
 Dim ColorIndex As String
 Dim Findr     As Range
 Dim MyRange As Range

 Set MyRange = ActiveCell
 CurValue = ActiveCell.Value

 With ActiveCell
    Set Findr = Range("A1:A10").find(CurValue)
    If Not Findr Is Nothing Then
        ColorIndex = Findr.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
        MyRange.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
'        rngStart.Select
    End If
 End With

End Sub
```

This sub works perfectly.

However for the problem:
Now i want to call it whenever a cell changes but if I call the macro whenever a cell changes in my Sheet.I tried using the sheet sourcecode for every change.
But then it uses the cell the user jumps to after the change rather then the previous edited cell.

How do i get this Macro to call for every changed cell rather then the new select cell?

Comment: Put the code in `WorkSheet_Change` instead of `WorkSheet_SelectionChange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the following in the appropriate Worksheet object should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CurValue  As String
Dim ColorIndex As String
Dim Findr     As Range
For Each AC In Target.Cells
    CurValue = AC.Value
    Set Findr = Range("A1:A10").find(CurValue)
    If Not Findr Is Nothing Then
        ColorIndex = Findr.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
        AC.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Note - one of the A1:A10 needs to be blank, but the value in B next to the blank must have a *ColorIndex* value and cannot be blank. I'd suggest a zero to empty all colour out of the cell but I can't see what your sheet's 'empty' cells look like..

The `For..Each` loop is to handle where more than one cell is changed at once, it performs the colour-change on each changed cell.

Also, cells that 'change' due to the result of a formula changing, rather than an edit, will not change using this method.